# REST and SOAP Webservices

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, soapui

If given a REST or SOAP webservices URL, how can we find the method it offers.

`For ex: http://ipAddress:port/projectName/services`

Comment: >how can we find the method it offers<   REST Webservices mostly supports only the HTTP Methods POST/GET/PUT/DELETE etc (based upon the webservice implementation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tack **?wsdl** onto the end of the URL. If it returns the XML based WSDL document, then it is a SOAP based service.

Comment: Thanks dmarietta .. How abt the REST ?

Comment: Since REST can really be implemented in a wide variety of ways, there is not any one definitive way to say "yes that response is REST". For example, maybe it returns XML data; maybe JSON formatted data; or maybe it just returns an HTTP error code if there are unexpected or missing parameters.

Comment: REST services are not self-describing.